# Image stretches on some page loads

Tags: html, css, image

So on some page loads an image at the bottom of my website stretches horizontally.  If you go to [shadowverse.nge.io](http://shadowverse.nge.io) and scroll down to the bottom you will see the picture of the girl  on the left.  If you keep refreshing the page it will stretch horizontally sometimes and not others.  I have no idea what is causing this.

Thank you!

Intended:
[image: intended]
Unintended:
[image: unintended]

Comment: The image has a max-width of 100%, so it should never escape its bounds. Can you please post a screenshot showing **intended** behaviour, and another showing **unintended behaviour**? If you're talking about the split second it takes to 'adjust' its size on page load, that's due to the CSS loading on your page, and there's not much you can do about that, other than optimisation.

Comment: Hey Obsidian, thanks for the tip.  And no im not talking about the flash of unstyled content.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!